# Can't get new Rails app with Devise to display sign_in/sign_up pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, turbolinks

I get the following error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Devise::Sessions#new

Showing C:/Users/me/RubymineProjects/my_project/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

  (in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/turbolinks-1.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):
3  <head>
4    <title>HourlyTracker</title>
5    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
6    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
7    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8  </head>
9  <body>
```

I'm using the 3.0.0rc version of Devise, which is supposed to work with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0rc1. I'm on Windows x64.

Comment: You might be missing `therubyracer` gem; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8882423/429758

Comment: I believe that your issue could be possibly something to do with `data-turbolinks-track` I had a conflicting issue with turbolinks in my application. Once I had removed it from my application everything was fine

Comment: @PrakashMurthy - I read that too about therubyracer. Unfortunately I can't get therubyracer to install on Windows :(. Well, more specifically, libv8, which therubyracer depends on, doesn't work with Windows.

Comment: @at you could try and look at the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows some of these answers may just help you.

Comment: @David - those responses seem to suggest therubyracer and libv8 won't install on Windows but it doesn't matter anyway. But Devise suddenly needs therubyracer and therefore won't run on Windows?

Comment: include the 'execjs' and 'therubyracer' gems in your gem file and run 'bundle install' that's it.

Comment: @MohdAnas - execjs was already in my gem list, therubyracer seems like it doesn't install on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Click here and install node.js' windows version. It will solve your problem: http://nodejs.org/

On windows, on linux and on mac, the best V8 engine is nodejs and you don't have to install any other gem for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "`turbolinks`" within assets group, get it out.

I had similar issue where my test failed because one or all of following gems were within test group,

```
  gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
  gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
  gem "haml-rails"
  gem 'gumby-framework'
  gem "modernizr-rails"
```

but when I got them out of the group my test passed.

Answer (score 0):

This is 3 years late, but for anybody who finds this, the error the OP got most likely means that he has a typo in his coffee files. He likely typed something that Coffee doesn't recognize.