# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Say#hello Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, execjs

created a controller

```
rails generate controller Say hello
```

I navigate to the localhost it returns an execjs error

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Say#hello
Showing C:/Users/Roman/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/my_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:


  (in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):       
  < <head>
<title>MyApp</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
selected red this line:
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

What to do?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
%= stylesheet_link_tag    'applications', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    selected red this line:
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'applications', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`
```

Comment: Pure code may be a good thing, but without a clear explanation, there's no way to tell if this would (or would not) be a solution to the problem