# Rails and coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

For some reason rails is not liking the following code and I am not sure why.  It seems to be throwing an Uncaught Error: ExecJS::RuntimeError.

The file that it is complaining about is my schedules.js.coffee and the only code I have in file is the following:

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

jQuery ->
  $(document).on "page:change", ->
    $("#sched_date").datepicker
      changeMonth: true
      changeYear: true
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      duration: "slow"
  return
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You need to install a JS runtime, like nodejs -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror

Comment: But I have other coffee script files with very, very similar code and those seem to be fine.  I also have gem 'jquery-rails' in my gemfile.

Comment: Could you include the full error message?

Comment: Here is what I am seeing.  ExecJS::RuntimeError in StaticPages#home and then it points to the following line in application.html.erb file, which has not been changed in quite a while:  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing this issue.  Seems that execjs was updated and there is an issue with the runtimes.rb file and windows 8 64bit.  Once I edited the runtimes.rb file (had done this a while back when I initially installed rails) things are back to normal.

So, my only other question is, what gem updates execjs?  Is it jquery-rails?  If so I will look at specifying the exact version in my gemfile to stop this happening again.

The following link was helpful in fixing this issue:

[Execjs runtimes.rb fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)