# ExecJS::RuntimeError in ChatRooms#show

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

The issue I'm having:

[image]

This is my room.coffee file, and everything works well.

```js
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  messages = $('#messages')
  if $('#messages').length > 0

    App.global_chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
        channel: "ChatRoomsChannel"
        chat_room_id: messages.data('chat-room-id')
      },
      connected: ->
        # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

      disconnected: ->
        # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

      received: (data) ->
        # Data received

      send_message: (message, chat_room_id) ->
        @perform 'send_message', message: message, chat_room_id: chat_room_id
```

```css
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

#messages {
  max-height: 450px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  .avatar {
    margin: 0.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><%= @chat_room.title %></h1>

<div id="messages" data-chat-room-id="<%= @chat_room.id %>">
  <%= render @chat_room.messages %>
</div>

<hr>

<%= form_for @message, url: '#' do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'chat_room_id', @chat_room.id %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control' %>
    <small class="text-muted">From 2 to 1000 characters</small>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

But it shows ExecJS::RuntimeError after I added the code down below in the same file.

```js
$('#new_message').submit (e) ->
      $this = $(this)
      textarea = $this.find('#message_body')
      if $.trim(textarea.val()).length > 1
        App.global_chat.send_message textarea.val(), messages.data('chat-room-id')
        textarea.val('')
      e.preventDefault()
      return false
```

I did search similar problems a lot, and most people who use pc encountered this issue. But I'm using mac, I have no idea why I got this error as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need javascript runtime environment

Install `node.js` or add `therubyracer` gem

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

**OR**
Add `therubyracer` gem in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your room.coffee file your code is indented using two spaces. In the code you have added indentation is more than that. If you outdent the section after `$('#new_message').submit (e) ->` to match two space indentation the syntax error will be resolved.